# Dynamically Inject ID3 in FFMPEG Live Stream

Tags: ffmpeg, live-streaming, http-live-streaming, live-video

I am trying to find out if there is a way with FFMPEG to dynamically inject ID3 tags during live streaming.

Basically I use FFMPEG to stream a live HLS stream from a video device, while another piece of software is generating events that need to be synced up in the front-end player.

I want to be able to have the event generating software encode the event in the live stream, so I know that the event is synced up with the video.

Comment: ID3 tags aren't generally used in streaming.  What player are you using that can read ID3 out of an HLS stream?

Comment: JWPlayer at the moment, and I've done it before with HLS.JS, but that one had no support for reading the ID3 tag event in iOS. JWPlayer does seem to have some support for it on iOS, because using the MediaLive (Amazon) setup it was working. Would you suggest another way to get timed metadata into the live stream?

Comment: I'm sure you've read this- (also there's a part about ID3 in DASH) https://www.unified-streaming.com/blog/how-make-your-media-streams-smarter-using-timed-metadata. or a quick search found this https://helpx.adobe.com/adobe-media-server/dev/timed-metadata-hls-hds-streams.html#output_in_hls