# Inserting meta data into a live video stream

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, http-live-streaming

I want to achieve the following, but it remains unclear if this is possible.

---

**The current scenario:**

> Someone is streaming a video with audio through
>   OBS to a media server, clients connect through a website.

*[OBS Stream/Video Stream] -> [AWS/External Streaming Service] -> Clients*

---

**The wanted scenario:**

> capture this stream through a custom media server
>   and manipulate it by injecting certain metadata at certain moments
>   **during the livestream**. Note the importance of **live**.

*[OBS Stream/Video Stream] -> [My Custom Node.js Server to insert metadata] -> [AWS/External Streaming Service] -> Clients*

---

**The idea:**

The idea is that I want to synchronize the stream to some popup for example. The default protocol stream seems to be RTMP from OBS, but maybe this can be changed. At a given time during the livestream, an html5 videoplayer on the website can read these tags from the livestream (through some additional library such as video.js) and tell the JS application to show some text. **In the end, it boils down to synchronizing the video stream to a text stream (eg from a websocket connection)**

**Potential solutions:**

- ***ID3 tags***. I read about ID3 tags in MP3 files, but this does not seem to be what i'm looking as it needs a complete .mp3 file **upfront** and is not used for streams ([Dynamically Inject ID3 in FFMPEG Live Stream](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54862783/1809825)). What I want is to dynamically inject metadata into this stream. For example, inject an id at any time (dynamically chosen) which references to a database for example should suffice.
- ***LTC/Linear Time Code/SMPTE*** is this possible to embed that in a video stream somehow with node.js? that would enable me to match timings with an id on the client.

Is this possible to do given an incoming video stream with audio? and if so, what is the format of the stream and how do I inject metadata?

---

**EDIT**: it seems RTMP is not supported without flash in the browser. This is a no-go so I will need to use another stream format such as HLS/FLV?

Comment: `what is the format of the stream` What is  the format the player expects? I assume you want to read the metadata back out?

Comment: @szatmary I don't really care I guess, any decent supported format that a HTML5 video tag can play.

Comment: There is no supported inband metadata format for MSE. You will need to research players that support such things. I’m not sure if hls.js supports in band ID3, but it may.

Comment: MSE? Also, reading ID3 is not a problem (if this is the solution). However the problem is inserting these tags dynamically into a video livestream as from what I gathered this is done upfront (and not timed?, eg i want 5 ID3 tags every 10 seconds from a certain point, it seems ID3 tags is just metadata for one file).

Comment: @CaptainObvious According to [the comment dated the 15th March 2020](https://obsproject.com/forum/threads/youtube-live-360-metadata.82785/) on this site , this feature you want is not yet available with obs, but is in progress. You can add metadata when creating your clip, but at present, this can't be edited once the video is playing. These features are only available for outgoing videos in any case, i,e, where you are the publisher, not incoming streams

Comment: "*it boils down to synchronizing the video stream to a text stream*" - I'm pretty certain that annotating each text stream item with a video timestamp is the easier solution for that problem. Sure, having only a single stream to broadcast and and decode on the client(s) is more elegant, but much harder.

Comment: @Bergi but again, how do I know the current "timestamp"/"event" of the livestream? This needs to be included in the videostream and this is what i'm searching for  (let's assume i have the text stream upfront mapping certain timestamp/events to text). The video livestream is actually the driver of the whole scenario, but these timestamp/events need to be injected dynamically/manully in the livestream when someone clicks a button (to keep it simple)

Comment: I'm pretty certain that the playback library you're using at the client offers a way to get the current playtime (i.e. which frame, measured from the start of the stream, is currently shown), possibly even allows attaching callbacks for certain play times.

Comment: Re your edit: and the same should apply for the recording side of the stream

Comment: Sorry if I am missing the point but this initially looks overly complicated. Why not just have a second service that you connect to via web sockets that provides the additional information? It would stay in sync with the stream. It would also be easier to manage as technology evolves (one encoding method might change, which would require a rewrite of a metadata based solution, but require nothing more than a module install if you wrote the service separately (as it won't be affected by the format requested.) Would also work on legacy browsers that may not accept meta data via a video stream

Comment: @GrahamRitchie This is what I initially thought on doing, however the problem remains: synchronizing these streams. It is likely that the videostream/textstream runs a bit behind, so "they would stay in sync with the stream" is far from trivial. Hence, why i need some information in the stream (timestamp or id) so I can sync it to the websocket stream. Also my application requires precise timing of the streams (i should be able to match them with max few 100ms of difference, so seconds is not enough). Currently looking into the Webm format, seems to be well supported.

Comment: If you are using web sockets on node for example the maximum delay you should expect is 100ms (assuming resources on server are sufficient). If you delayed the stream by 1 second deliberately (for example, 500ms would probably be enough for slow mobile phones that can't process things quickly) you could then send the information with timestamps ahead of time and achieve perfect synchronisation. As I said it was just a thought and might not fit your use case but it does seem more maintainable and likely to have the greatest browser compatibility.

Comment: it will go wrong and delays will occur, maybe because of the receiving side and not the sending server side. I don't want to make assumptions that it will likely be fine in most of the cases. The application is time sensitive in the sense that from the perspective of the user, things need to match exactly. The textstream can be known (a bit) up front (ids -> action), but the issue is linking these to a *live* videostream (random time  -> id). The random time is not known upfront which creates the need to inject dynamic inband metadata at the exact timestamp (hence my custom nodejs to do this)

Comment: maybe I just have a wrong view of what is possible with livestream videos and metadata. I thought this was used quite a lot. Although it seems to be the case, but only for upfront/static/complete files, not for live. Given the lack of answers I might have been wrong.

Answer (score 5):

Sounds like using something like [Liquidsoap](https://github.com/savonet/liquidsoap) as your streaming server would do the trick for inserting the metadata into the stream. Plenty of options for manipulating metadata for you to explore.

As for client side decoding you could perhaps use a javascript readable stream within a service worker to split the server output into metadata/video and process as you see fit.

I did a similar thing for processing inband metadata on an infinite mp3 stream which might give you some ideas on where to start. You can find the code for that [here](https://github.com/cryptiksouls/icecast-shoutcast-metadata-grabber)

Comment: Can you provide more details? What should the format of the incoming videostream be? What kind of meta data can I insert? In what form, ID3 tags? It seems your proposed a solution for mp3 files, but not for videostreams?

Comment: Liquidsoap can cope with many formats. I can't give you an example specific to your use case as I haven't had to implement one but the project is extensively documented. My service worker which parses in band metadata was written for use with an mp3 stream but all its doing is consuming a stream of data from a server and splitting it into file and metadata based upon the metadata being spliced in to the original file at set byte intervals. Whether the original file is mp3 or something else isn't really relevant as to how it works.

Comment: I've rewarded you with the bounty since this is the only answer. However, I'll dive a bit deeper in the implementation later since i'm still not convinced this is answer to my question.